# How to add response message from repository instead of controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, httpresponse

I want to set error message from repository before controller return 'ok' or 'BadRequest'

```
[HttpPost(Name = "CreateAsyncEmployee")]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateAsync(RegisterModel model)
{
    Employee employee = _repositoryContext.Employee.CreateAsync(model);
    return OK();
}
```

add message to response http from repository:

```
public async Task<Employee> CreateAsync(RegisterModel model)
{
    ....
    Httpresponse response = new HttpResponse();
    response.Current.write("register completed.");
    return employee;
}
```

Comment: Actually repositories should not be dealing with http request and response. That's what the controllers are for. Repositories should only be doing data operations in integration with DataAccess Layers. I would suggest you should do this in controller.

Comment: You can do `return Ok("register completed.");` in controller action method